# Chrome cuts off ghost image when using position sticky/fixed

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I'm attempting to use HTML5 drag and drop and `position: fixed` to drag elements from a menu that stays in a fixed position on the left-side of the screen.

The following code works fine in Safari and Firefox, but when I try it in Chrome, after scrolling, the "ghost" image produced from the drag and drop API is not visible. If you scroll just right, you can drag a portion of the ghost image, which indicates to me that it's being clipped in some strange fashion. Setting the position of the `left` div to `absolute` works properly but I'd rather not use JS to compute the positioning if I can help it.

I did create a fiddle for this, but it has some other really strange issues running in Safari and Firefox (though it does show the problem in Chrome):
https://jsfiddle.net/e4fvrr5y/

Here is the full code I'm using to test:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
        }
        .left {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: #0f0;
            position: fixed;
        }
        .right {
            margin-left: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 3000px;
            background: linear-gradient(white, black);
        }

        .draggable {
            background-color: #00f;
            padding: 20px;
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="left">
        <div class="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Draggable element</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>

    <script>
        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", "foo");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Searching online I found the following bug report for Chromium: [Issue 605119](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=605119&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=draggable&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=)

It seems related, as it's talking about position relative being the culprit. But that's nearly two years old, and has been reported fixed, so that's likely been merged into Chrome by this point. Has anyone else encountered this issue, and if so, what steps did you take to fix it?

Comment: It may be related to this bug : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=798182

Comment: Yes it does appear related! Were you able to find any sort of workaround? I've tried a few things but haven't gotten anything to work really well (aside from using a third party drag and drop which I'd rather not do)

Comment: I was able to find a workaround for my particular case but it won't apply to yours (replacing CSS transforms with top/left positioning). I would suggest you to open a new issue with your repro on the chromium issue tracker.

Comment: Ok I might do that if I can't get Lorenzo's solution to work.

Comment: A bug fix has just landed in Chrome Canary today. I can confirm that it solves this bug as well. I'm going to post an answer here with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that appeared in chrome 63.0.3223.0 (see this [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=798182)).

According to the issue tracker, this should be fixed in the next chrome stable release (64.x) in a few weeks.

Note that the fix is already available in Chrome Canary.

**UPDATE 25-01-2018**

Chrome 64 is now available

Comment: Ok that sounds perfect, so hopefully that will clear it up. Thanks for the info!

Comment: As a (rather late) followup, this no longer is a problem in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome requires the element being dragged be visible to the browser when the drag operation starts. I had the same problem, I got around it by cloning the draggable element appending it to the body and positioning it over the draggable element in the fixed container on dragstart. Next I set the clone as the element dragImage. Last, I remove the clone on dragend. I was using jQuery here is my fix hope it helps:

```
var $clone = null;
document.addEventListener( 'dragstart',  function( ev ) {
    var $el = $( ev.target );
    $clone = $el.clone(); 
    $clone.css( {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: $el.offset().top,
        left: $el.offset().left,
        width: $el.width()
    } );
    $('body').append( $clone )
    ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage( $clone[ 0 ], 0, 0);
} );

document.addEventListener( 'dragend', function( ev ){
    $clone.remove();
    $clone = null;
} );
```

Comment: Ok I'll give that a shot, sounds promising. I kinda figured that was why Chrome wasn't handling it, but wasn't totally sure how to get around it. Will update with results.